# Multiline html variables in webpy

Tags: python, templates, multiline, web.py

I have a snippet in template like this:

```
$ html = """<p id="address">
    Адрес:
    <span id="postcode">123456</span>,
    <span id="city">Москва</span>,
    <span id="street">Красная площадь</span>,
    <span id="houseNumber">д.1</span>,
    <span id="addhouseNumber">стр.1</span>,
    <span id="officeNumber">офис 12</span>
</p>"""
$:htmlLoop(entry, 'address', html)
```

When I try to render it I get traceback:

```
extend_([u'</p>"""\n'])








                           ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

And it doesn't depend on if I breal lines with `\` or `"""`.

Comment: Are you surea about that output? It looks *very* strange.

Comment: I just need to duplicate the same `<p>` in my page as many times as there are entries in db... What's seems strage? even if i have empty multiline `"""<p><\p>"""`, I get the same error. Btw, in single line it works((

Comment: What version of python are you using? print([u'</p>"""\n']) works on python2 but gives an error on python3.

Answer (score 1):

web.py doesn't support triple-quoted strings. You can accomplish what you're trying to do like this:

```
$def html():
    <p id="address">
        Адрес:
        <span id="postcode">123456</span>,
        <span id="city">Москва</span>,
        <span id="street">Красная площадь</span>,
        <span id="houseNumber">д.1</span>,
        <span id="addhouseNumber">стр.1</span>,
        <span id="officeNumber">офис 12</span>
    </p>
$:htmlLoop(entry, 'address', html())
```